# IES rotate in cycles is wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, texture-coordinates

How can I turn the point light source to the left?
The example shows that the light to the right is good. And when I turn it to the left, there is almost no glow. I tried to return both the texture through the nodes and the light itself. I tried also use texture coordinate node and other methods.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Blender 3.6.8